# Slug is not passing 'question mark'

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am creating slug from title in a `Laravel` based website. When I am creating, fetching slug everything is working fine. But when I am trying to see the details of the post, I am passing slug in the route. But the slug is missing its question mark.

I am using the following code to make the slug:

```
public function make_slug($string) {
   return preg_replace('/\s+/u', '-', trim($string));
}
```

I am using this code because that site is used for other language than english.
This code makes the slug just fine. 
For example:

My post title is: What is Lorem Ipsum?

My slug will be: what-is-lorem-ipsum?

I am saving and fetching this slug just fine.

My details route looks like: 
`https://example-v2.dev/post/what-is-lorem-ipsum?`

This route is even shown in my browser URL.
But when I am getting it in my controller the slug becomes like the following:

`what-is-lorem-ipsum`

The question mark is removed.
Which results in an error as I am querying database using slug.
What is the problem here? Also what is the fix?

Comment: `?` is a special character in URLs, delimiting query parameters.

Comment: @deceze oh yes. Thank you very much. But is there any way to pass it?

Comment: You really should avoid passing `?` in your slugs. What if you need to pass any $_GET param after ?

Comment: If you want the slug to contain a literall question mark, you will need to use [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on it before you output the link. However, that won't look as nice, which is why most systems don't allow it in slugs.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone for the feedback. :)